# Simple Regex skips always first character on a line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a very strange effect when using a particular regex in JavaScript. If I use [`/^|.+/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/tjBPu0/1), it always skips the first character on a line.

According to regex101.com, it doesn't happen with pcre (php), but does happen in JavaScript, Python, and GoLang. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, empty matches *still increment* the current index being searched in the string by one. If *anything* is matched starting at position X in the string, the next match must start at least at position X + 1. (PCRE does not exhibit this behavior; empty matches which don't consume any characters permit an additional non-empty match immediately following that empty match)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks so much for helping me understand!